# Create a dictionary of all unique keys in a column and store correlation co-efficients of other columns as associated values

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

There is a dataset with three columns:

- Col 1 : Name_of_Village
- Col 2: Average_monthly_savings
- Col 3: networth_in_dollars

So, I want to create a dictionary "Vill_corr" where the **key values** are the name of the villages and the associated values are the correlation co-effient between Col2 & Col3 using **Pandas**.

I am aware of methods of calculating the correlation co-efficients, but not sure how to store it against each Village name key,

`corr = df["Col2"].corr(df["Col3"])`

Please help.

Comment: What do you need help with? Do you know how to get the correlation coefficients? Do you know how to convert Pandas data structures to dict? Please [edit] to clarify. For more tips, see [ask], [mre], and [reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Oops, I thought you mentioned Pandas but apparently not. It'd help to mention what library(s) you're using.

Comment: Sorry, was in a hurry to post. Added some additional details. Please see @wjandrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and [`Series.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.corr.html):

```
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name_of_Village': np.random.choice(list('ABCD'), size=100),
                   'Average_monthly_savings': np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=100),
                   'networth_in_dollars': np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=100),
                  })

out = (df.groupby('Name_of_Village')
         .apply(lambda g: g['Average_monthly_savings'].corr(g['networth_in_dollars']))
      )
```

Output:

```
Name_of_Village
A   -0.081200
B   -0.020895
C    0.208151
D   -0.010569
dtype: float64
```

As dictionary:

```
out.to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'A': -0.08120016678846673,
 'B': -0.020894973553868202,
 'C': 0.20815112481676484,
 'D': -0.010569152488799725}
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a question, can I add `to_dict()` to the first line itself?

Comment: @Pragyaditya yes of course ;)